# Is recursive use of eval() an alright way to inspect the execution of a program?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, interpreter

I've been building a basic live-evaluation javascript development environment (I call it the [WEPL](http://github.com/tehgeekmeister/wepl).) over the past few days, and realized it'd be nice to be able to associate error messages to line numbers.  Unfortunately, eval() doesn't provide a nice way to do this, that I can find.

The solution I've come up with so far is to transform the source before eval() so that it's a set of nested calls to a wrapper to eval() that records some information before eval, checks to see if the eval succeeds, and then uses that info to output more useful troubleshooting information to the user.

My question is, why might this be a bad idea?  What problems do I need to solve to make sure this works well?

An example of the sort of transformation I mean, just to make this concrete.

This

```
if (cond) {
  return foo + bar;
}
else {
  return baz + quux;
}
```

becomes this

```
if (myEval('cond')) {
  return myEval("myEval(\"foo\") + myEval(\"bar\")");
else {
  return myEval("myEval(\"baz\") + myEval(\"quux\")");
}
```

Where I obviously didn't wrap the highest level, though I could've, and the programmatic version would.

Comment: It will certainly be much slower. Of course, whether that is acceptable or not is up to you.

Comment: Should be acceptable for the short term.  If it becomes a problem, that can be dealt with later.  I'm targeting this at helping new coders learn, not being a replacement for what any experienced developer uses.

Comment: Uhh. This is wrong on so many levels... you can't handle scope, or closures, object-oriented code, not to mention that you have to write a Javascript parser just to figure out how to break up the code correctly.

Comment: Isn't scope handled implicitly?

Comment: Also, what are the problems with closures and object oriented code?  Knowing these would be very useful for me.  I'd love to see a fully fleshed out answer from you.  (As for the parser, I'm not afraid of writing a parser.)

Comment: Not to mention the crazy memory use - thhe length of the escape sequences would increase exponentially with expression depth.

Comment: I think you'd be better off stealing ideas from HTML5 SourceMaps

Comment: Yep, it would.  That is not itself a problem, given the intended use case.  Would still love to see a fully fleshed out answer.  These are good points.  I'd love to know more detail about your thoughts.

Comment: @MattWhipple, taking a look at that now.  Never heard of it.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/ - good place to start

Comment: @MattWhipple I don't see how source maps help here.  Would you mind explaining?  The problem at hand is that eval() doesn't give a stack trace, not mapping minified code to original source.

Comment: It provides an approach to reliably create a reference from evaluated code to the original source which could then be used to recreate a stack trace.  It's higher level goals are divergent but the actual purpose is the same.  It would certainly not be a quick fix but should have some optimized approaches under the surface.

Comment: @MattWhipple ah.  I see.  Good to know about, but probably not ideal for beginners to have to figure out the chrome dev panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work if you want to accept even remotely complex scripts. A few potential problems:

### Scope

```
var i = 1; // global scope
!function() {
    var i = 2; // function scope
}();
alert(i); // 1
```

vs.

```
myEval('var i = 1;'); // global scope
myEval('!function() {
    myEval(\'var i = 2;\'); // eval has global scope, always
}();');
myEval('alert(i);'); // 2
```

### Closures

```
!function() {
    var i = 1; // local to outer function
    !function() { // inherits context from outer function
        alert(i); // 1
    }();
}();
```

vs.

```
myEval('!function() {
    myEval(\'var i = 1;\'); // local to outer function
    myEval(\'!function() { // eval has global scope; myEval inherits from wherever it was defined
        myEval(\\\'alert(i);\\\'); // undefined
    }();\');
}();');
```

### this

```
var obj = {
    n: 1,
    f: function() {
        return this.n; // this is the object f is called from
    }
}
alert(obj.f()); // 1
```

vs.

```
myEval('var obj = {
    n: myEval(\'1\'),
    f: myEval(\'function() {
           return myEval(\\\'this.n\\\'); // this is always the window in eval
       }')
}');
myEval('alert(obj.f());'); // undefined
```

### Escape creep

You need to escape every quote, and you need to escape escape signs as well. In code with lots of objects, closures, inner functions etc. this will result in escape signs becoming unmanageable:

```
!function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#foo').click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.post('/', function(res) {
                     log(res);
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}();
```

(note that this is not a particularly contrived or complicated example, it only involves a delyed action with a callback firing on a certain event)

```
myEval('!function() {
    myEval(\'$(myEval(\\\'function() {
        myEval(\\\\\\\'$(\\\\\\\'#foo\\\\\\\').click(myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'function() {
            myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'setTimeout(myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'function() {
                myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'$.post('/', myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'function(res) {
                     myEval(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'log(res);\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\');
                }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'));\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\');
            }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'), 1000);\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\');
        }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'));\\\\\\\');
    }\\\'));\');
}();');
```

You can probably see what I am getting at.

Comment: Awesome.  This is the sort of problems I wanted to find out about before I put any work into this.

I'm looking into ways I can make a chrome/firefox extension to hook into their javascript debuggers instead, now.  Seems better.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar when working on an extension for IE.  I ended up creating a global variable called 'lineNumber' and I transformed the code to be more like this:

```
lineNumber = 1; if (cond) {
  lineNumber = 2; return foo + bar;
}
else {
  lineNumber = 5; return baz + quux;
}
```

Of course, I made to make sure I used curly braces around all blocks and had to keep my coding simple enough to avoid confusing my poor lame parser -- but it got me through it.

Comment: That'd get me line numbers, and would be much faster.  I think my approach might be useful for more things in the future, but I might delay going to that extreme and use this for a while.